# R: Is integration of a sum faster than double sum of easy calculation?

Tags: r

I have a function which involves a sum.

I need to calculate the integral of this function *squared*.

I can easily use `integrate()` here and it's okay fast.

But I actually don't need to use `integrate()`. Since

1. the square of a sum is a double sum,
2. and the integral of a double sum is the double sum of an integral of the inner-most terms,
3. and I can calculate the integral analytically of the inner-most terms

I can also calculate my integral by following the above step, so that my final calculation is a double-sum over the integral calculated analytically (i.e. I know what the actual expression for the integral is).

Would this be faster or slower than the above `integrate()` method **generally speaking** (i.e. what's your hunch and why). I know a double-sum is slow, but I can always use Rcpp.

I can't test this for myself since I don't know what the formula in step 3. above is. I don't want to spend time calculating unless I know if it is worth it...

Comment: This is so vague... rather than speculate, maybe just code up a simplified example and test that? At least provide a concrete example? `integrate` uses sums internally, so whether *you* do the double sum or you hide it with integrate, it's still happening.

Comment: Use rbenchmark package to test performance of different options

Comment: **"integrate uses sums internally, so whether you do the double sum or you hide it with integrate, it's still happening."** .... uh yeah .... that's the whole point of the question. Whether Integrate will do them faster or not...

Comment: This could be interesting. But I (for one) am not curious enough to spend the time to generate a workable sample for you. Suggestion: use `microbenchmark` or `rbenchmark` on your own use of both methods. If you aren't willing to take the time to do that, then unless somebody else has already done the work (or is bored), perhaps this isn't a great question on StackOverflow.